# How can I solve this problem with the Java Intent?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I convertetd some code from java into Kotlin.

```
fun backhome(home: View) {
    val intent_home = Intent(this, MainActivity)
    startActivity(intent_home)
```

---

```
fun backhome(home: View) {
    val intent_home = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)



    startActivity(intent_home)
}
```

First I tried the first code and this was the error on Intent: 
none of the following functions can be called with the argument supplied
(Context!,Class<*>!)
(String!,Uri!)

With the second version I had an error by class.java as unresolved reference

[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ8s0.png)

Comment: `Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)`, you need to get Java class this way.

Comment: Thats what I used in the second excample, that didn't worked either

Comment: Does `Main2Activity` exist? In your previous code, it's just `MainActivity`

Comment: Yes it does and when I try to write the first code like the second, there is the same problem

Comment: Show your Gradle module file.

Comment: build.gradle is a link for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are missing Kotlin plugins in your project.

In your **Build.Gradle(App level)** file, add these.

[image]

Also, in the same file, add this in the `dependencies { }`

```
dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

In your **Build.Gradle(Project level)** file, make sure you have these written in `BuildScript` closure.

```
buildscript {
  ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
  repositories {
     google()
     jcenter()
  }

 dependencies {
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
  }
}
```

After sync, clean/rebuild the project. Hopefully, the error would be gone.

Comment: I tried it like you said, and now when I try to sinc the project, the plugins (even com.android.application) aren't found                         ERROR: Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.